# There is a bug in swiperjs when scaling slider images if the page is scrolled. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, swiper.js

Link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-zoom-forked-z7wyyr?file=%2Findex.html&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A27%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A30%2C%22startColumn%22%3A27%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A30%7D%5D).
Link to the mobile [demo](https://z7wyyr-5000.csb.app/) (scroll down to the bottom).
If the swiper is at the beginning of the page, there is no bug, otherwise when zooming in on the image with two fingers, the image flies away.

I looked through the documentation, but there is no information on how to influence this.
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#zoom